# Function like $.datepicker.formatDate for formatting time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `$.datepicker.formatDate` I can only format a date, meaning if I pass in a Date object, I can only get the date part of it formatted but not the time part.

Is there any equivalent function which allows the time part to also be formatted/parsed, preferably in the same syntax?

I'm using the following datetime plugin:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

But it doesn't seem to have an equivalent formatDate function that I can use.

Comment: look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Post a code example, and I can accept!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The datepicker's [formatDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) method does not have any option to format time, for that look at a datetime library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Ex

```
var date = new Date();

var df = moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
alert(df)
```

and

```
var d = moment('2013-09-11 14:44:03', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(d.format('M/D/YYYY h:m A'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HA9Z8/)

Comment: Can you add how I would do it if I have a string of a date, e.g '2013-09-11 14:44:03'? e.g a MySQL datetime field retrieved from db? thanks

Comment: @ClickUpvote what is the desired output is it a date object/date in another format

Comment: The output should be just a string of the date formatted in another way, e.g MySQL date time into: 9/8/2013 2:44 PM`