# Convert mysql timestamp's time to am/pm format

Tags: mysql, sql, select, timestamp, date-format

I have the following variable which contains  mysql timestamp value.
`var dateReceived='2014-11-07 16:21:50'`
Please help me to change the time in 12 O'clock(AM/PM) format using jQuery.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946698/changing-date-time-format-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use [**DATE_FORMAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to convert the format of date

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-11-07 16:21:50', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2014-11-07 04:21:50 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

this code might help you in your code.

```
var myDate = new Date('2014-11-07 16:21:50');
var ouputDate = myDate.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: when i try to put my variable in the Date(),like `var myDate = new Date(dateReceived);` it is showing `invalid date`.I must put the variable (`dateReceived` ,which store the dynamic value fetched from database) in the Date().

Comment: it is because the data coming from mySQL in your  variable is different from the format we have used here, it should be year-date-month hour:min:seconds or date-month-year hour:min: seconds