# angularjs convert date string to human readable format

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the date string from server in the following format:

```
$scope.dateform = {
   "dob": "22-06-1980"
}
```

But i want to convert into GMT form using angularjs inside controller.

```
Sat Jun 22 1980 00:12:00 GMT+0530
```

Is there any way to convert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Date Time Format using jquery/javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946698/changing-date-time-format-using-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly simple to do in angular you use the build in date feature.

In your controller store the date in a variable

```
$scope.dateVariable = my-non-human-date-string
```

In your view simply output it inside handle bars with angular's date filter attached to it.

```
{{dateVariable | date : "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"}}
```

You can also find different formats for dates at the following link.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 2):

Its really simple if you use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

what you have to do is

```
$scope.dateform = {
   "dob": "22-06-1980"
} 
var momentObj = moment($scope.dateform.dob, 'DD-MM-YYYY');

console.log(momentObj .toString()); // here you will the the format you need
```

here i have create a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NnbRKkJeeiArhyaRiH5R?p=preview) for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use momentjs

```
moment("25-12-1995", "DD-MM-YYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use date filter in html code in `angularjs`.

Like this

```
date:'dd/MM/yyyy'
```