# Retrieve datetime field in dd/mm/yyyyy hh:mm AM/PM format from sharepoint list using REST api

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint

Looking for help!!!
I'm using REST API to retrieve SharePoint list items. Date time field returns value in 2016-10-01T16:00:00Z. Is there a way to retrieve date in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM format or convert the date to required format using jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Please refer this link --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946698/changing-date-time-format-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to have a look at the library [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

You can parse the input string with it as it is explain in the library doc.

Add the library to your `<head>` like:      `<script type="text/javascript" src="[If not in the folder containing your html file, specifiy your path beneath the folder containing it + "/"]moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>`

Then in your `<body>` try:

`<script type="text/javascript">
var test = moment("2016-10-01T16:00:00Z").format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
alert("test: " + test);
</script>`

It will display: "Test: 01/10/2016 06:00:00 PM"

It shows 6pm because I am located at UTC+2 hours.

Comment: You're welcome, since it is the solution to your problem, could you validate answer and upvote it so we both earn reputation:)